# \addcontentsline adds an unwanted indent

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, exercises

## Prologue

I'm using the `exercise` package and trying to harmonize its layout with `memoir`.

This question is quite involved to illustrate, so I'll break it up into several Acts. I'll present the relevant source and then screenshot of the output.

---

## Act I

Having everything at default, I create an `Exercise` environment.

```
\begin{Exercise}[title=Theory of Relativity]
    The theory of relativity was not a eureka moment. It was the result of steady work over a period of 10~years.
    \begin{align}
        E &= mc^2
    \end{align}
    \Question Why does \(E = mc^2\)?
\end{Exercise}
```

[image]

---

## Act II

I want to customize the header a bit, so I issued the following `\renewcommand` in the preamble. The indent before "The theory of..." doesn't look right. My desired layout wants to make the indent disappear.

```
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{%
    \hrule\medskip\noindent%
    \textbf{%
        \large%
        \ExerciseName\quad\ExerciseHeaderNB\ExerciseHeaderTitle %
        \ExerciseHeaderOrigin\medskip\\}%
    }
```

[image]

---

## Act III

I looked around in `texdoc exercise` and it doesn't document anything about the layout of the `Exercise` body. Yes, there is documentation about `Questions`, `subQuestions`, and `subsubQuestions`, but those do not apply to the `Exercise` body. So I looked around and I came to the definition of `\@@@ExeEnv`, which looks like this

```
\newcommand{\@@@ExeEnv}{%
    \vskip\ExerciseSkipBefore %
    \@QuestionLevel1 %
    \refstepExecounter %
    \begingroup%
        \@getExerciseInfo\ExerciseHeader %
        \addcontentsline{%
            \ext@exercise}{\toc@exercise}{%
                \ExerciseName\ %
                \theExercise\ %
                \expandafter{\itshape \ExerciseTitle}%
                    \hspace{.66em}%
        } %
    \endgroup%
}
```

---

## Act IV

So I try to dissect `\@@@ExeEnv`, adding and removing control sequences to see how they affect the output. With the following code in the preamble, I get what I want: the ugly indent disappears!

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@@@ExeEnv}{%
    \vskip\ExerciseSkipBefore \@QuestionLevel1 \refstepExecounter%
    \begingroup%
        \@getExerciseInfo\ExerciseHeader%
    \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

---

## Act V

But alas! I have removed the `\addcontentsline` command, which I suppose is important to maintaining a Table of Contents. So I try to add back the `\addcontentsline` from the original definition, but the ugly indent is back! Even a dummy `\addcontentsline` brings back the hideous indent, this time much more sneakier than the original.

```
\renewcommand{\@@@ExeEnv}{%
    \vskip\ExerciseSkipBefore \@QuestionLevel1 \refstepExecounter%
    \begingroup%
        \@getExerciseInfo\ExerciseHeader%
    \endgroup%
    \addcontentsline{}{}{}%
}
```

[image]

---

## Epilogue

Why does `\addcontentsline` add an unwanted indent? Where can I fix this? I'd also appreciate suggestions on better exercise packages which work better with `memoir`.

Adding a `\noindent` before the exercise body: (`\noindent The theory of...`) doesn't make the indent go away either. It's an inelegant solution as well.

Comment: That's a lot of code snippets! But I'd rather have one minimal working example. :-)

Comment: BTW, the problem seems to be not indentation, but a spurious space. I've changed the tags accordingly.

Comment: @lockstep, I did it this way to rule out as many "Have you tried..." responses as possible :)

Comment: I see .. but such code snippets should be added to a MWE, not replace it.

Comment: @lockstep: Right, will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra space ('Act III)', but you also want to `\ignorespaces` after your modified internal macro:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,exercise}
\renewcommand*\ExerciseHeader{%
  \hrule
  \medskip
  \noindent
  \begingroup
    \bfseries
    \large
    \ExerciseName\quad\ExerciseHeaderNB\ExerciseHeaderTitle
    \ExerciseHeaderOrigin
    \medskip
    \\
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@@@ExeEnv{%
    \vskip\ExerciseSkipBefore
    \@QuestionLevel1 %
    \refstepExecounter
    \begingroup%
        \@getExerciseInfo\ExerciseHeader %
        \addcontentsline{\ext@exercise}{\toc@exercise}
          {%
            \ExerciseName\ %
            \theExercise\ %
            \expandafter{\itshape \ExerciseTitle}%
            \hspace{.66em}%
          }%
    \endgroup
    \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}[title=Theory of Relativity]
    \noindent
    The theory of relativity was not a eureka moment. It was the result of steady work over a period of 10~years.
    \begin{align}
        E &= mc^2
    \end{align}
    \Question Why does \(E = mc^2\)?
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

Removing the space should deal with the issue.

Comment: I removed the space (and even the `\hspace`) but the indent becomes the one like in Act V.

Comment: @Kit: What we need is a proper minimal example, _i.e._ a short document that we can compile and try editing. Snippets are not a good way to get solutions.

Comment: @Kit: I've built a full minimal example, which seems to work for me. The key is to use `\ignorespaces` here to skip to the document content.